# Cypher query brokes neo4j when not execute

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I executed the query in the following segment of code but If there are 2 nodes faraway each other, The neo4j is broken;

```
START d=node(1), e=node(5)
MATCH p=shortestPath(d-[r:ROUTE*..15]-e)
WHERE all(x in relationships(p) WHERE x.RouteID=head(relationships(p)).RouteID)
RETURN p
limit 1
```

When I execute node 1 to 5 its working good and faster.When I execute node 5 to 45, it brokes neo4j.How can I solve that problem?

Thanks, Best regards

Comment: can you share a sample dataset?

Comment: There is sample dataset online.
http://brain.kaankilic.com:7474/browser/

Comment: I can see large number of duplicate relationships between nodes. Is it intentional?

Comment: yep,totally intentional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
START d=node(1), e=node(5)
MATCH p=shortestPath(d-[r:ROUTE*..45]-e)
WITH p, head(relationships(p)).RouteID as RouteID
WHERE all(x in relationships(p) WHERE x.RouteID=RouteID)
RETURN p
limit 1
```

you did a relationships(p) for any relationship in any path, so that's a big cross product.

Comment: Why it's not returning the relations? It's just returning nodes?